# How to rotate an object to face another in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity, vector

I'm having an issue where I can't seem to rotate my bullet appropriately whenever I spawn one. I currently have a capsule prefab I am testing with. I spawn it with the following code.

```
        GameObject b = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load<GameObject>("Prefabs/Bullet"));
```

I am using the following code to try and orient the bullet so that it lays along the imaginary ray between it's spawn location and the centre of the target.

```
    void Start() {
    go = InputController.instance.hit.transform.gameObject;
    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.parent.position.x, transform.parent.position.y - 5, transform.parent.position.z);
}

void Update () {
    transform.LookAt(go.transform.position);
    Vector3 rotation = transform.eulerAngles; //THIS IS THE LINE I NEED TO ALTER
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotation);       
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, go.transform.position, SPEED * Time.deltaTime);
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward * 10000000, Color.red); //DEBUGGING
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.up * 1000000, Color.green); //DEBUGGING
}
```

Essentially the issue I am having is how I can calculate the rotation of the object based on the two I have available.

As you can see the line that I can't seem to calculate is the second line of the Update method, what it needs to do is orient the `Vector3.up` direction of the object to run along the `Vector3` created by linking its position with the target location.

Interestingly the bullet is already laying horizontally but the `LookAt` method changes its rotation so I just need to fix it but I'm not sure on the math to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`LookAt`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) definition:

```
 public void LookAt(Transform target, Vector3 worldUp = Vector3.up);
```

The  default orientation, `Vector3.up`, it's not correct in your case (that's why the bullet is oriented upwards). Use:

```
transform.LookAt(go.transform.position, Vector3.right);
```

Comment: Thanks I don't know why that had to be so hard, just for reference I had to rotate it around x and not y if you want to update the answer in case others come looking for it.

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CWxKLkJUxbo